# Datastore (ndb) inserting linebreaks into content (type: TextProperty)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Foo(ndb.Model):
    bar = ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
    # other properties
```

I'm using jinja2 for templating:

```
{{ bar|safe }}
```

I 'put' in [this](http://cl.ly/image/1S3Z3b2v0v0U):

```
<p>I think it is always going to be challenging planning a wedding in a foreign country. 1234 Weddings was able to pre-arrange everything before our arrival and even meet us at the airport to attend to last minute details.<br> The wedding itself was even more amazing than we could have imagined and flawless. For our day, 1234 Weddings became a part of our family and our memories. We are so greatful for the professional communication and creativity that made our day so special.</p>
```

And ndb mangles the text, outputting [this](http://cl.ly/image/291w1x2s0S3C):

```
<p>I think it is always going to be challenging planning a wedding in a for=
eign country. 1234 weddings was able to pre-arrange everything before our a=
rrival and even meet us at the airport to attend to last minute details.<br=
>The wedding itself was even more amazing than we could have imagined and f=
lawless. For our day, 1234 Weddings became a part of our family and our mem=
ories. We are so greatful for the professional communication and creativity=
 that made our day so special.</p>
```

This only happens on my deployed site. The identical code on localhost doesn't produce this issue.

Possibly relevant:

- My local app engine doesn't have a persistant datastore.
- bar was originally of type 'StringProperty'. I noticed the issue after I changed the type to 'TextProperty', but there wasn't extensive testing before the change so it's possible the issue existed prior to that.

Any help would be appreciated.
TIA.

Comment: How do you put the text in the ndb entity? I understand: when you log the the entity after putting the entity, you see the "="'s.

Comment: Is the text being saved along with a file upload? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039813/symbols-in-gae-textproperty?rq=1

Comment: @voscausa Yes, that's correct. Also, text is put into the datastore like so:  


    def post(self):
        bar = self.request.get('bar')

        if bar:
            q = Foo()
            q.bar = bar
            q.put()

Comment: @Greg Yes, it is. Thanks for that link. It's the same problem. I'll follow the instructions there and see where it takes me.

Comment: @Greg Could you please post your solution as an answer, so that I can accept it and give you credit?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the blobstore upload handler that causes encoding problems with text submitted at the same time, comments here have a patch that has worked for me in the past: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749

Answer (score 0):

It's not NDB -- neither it no the Datastore ever does anything like this to your text. It looks like some kind of content-encoding, in particular quoted-printable, perhaps applied by the browser?

Comment: Thanks Guido,

The issue appears to be caused by a bug in the Blobstore handler. It is documented here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749


The monkey patch in comment 21 of that thread worked for me.